# Extract a "preview" of a blog post with rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, text, blogs

We store our blog posts in a text column in our database.  We need a "preview" of the blog post for our blog's home page.  That way, we can display the last couple days' blog posts with links to read the whole thing.

Is there a way in rails to pull out a certain amount of a text column? Maybe the first `x bytes`? I understand this won't be the same length for every blog post, but it should get it in the general area.

Or maybe do some html/css hack where we overflow a div and add an elipse to the div?

I could also see creating a separate "preview" column, but that feels very hacky.

Rails 3.2.1.  Database is MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I undertood correctly, you want something that transforms a long text entry into a limited preview text, like `This is a preview text, and it says that...`.

To do that, you can simple do something like:

```
text = post.text[0..100] + "..."
```

It basically gets the first 100 characters from the text.
If you want something more complex, that takes words in account (so you don't end up with things like `This is a previ...`, you can have a function that separates the text into words and add them to the final text until they reach the required length, like:

```
text = post.text
words = text.split(" ")
final_text = ""
words.each do |word|
    final_text += word if final_text.size + word.size < DESIRED_LENGTH
end
final_text += "..."
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way to split the text than .split(" "), but I don't have a ruby terminal in hand now to test

Comment: [Better way](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-excerpt) if loading the entire text of the post anyway

Comment: Argh, yes, I meant [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) actually. Thanks Steph.

Comment: That's why I love RoR, there's always a method that does whatever random crazy thing you want (not that truncating the text like this is uncommon, but I've seen some crazy things using "foo.methods"

Answer (score 1):

You can select the first (or the left-most) characters of text in a column:

```
SELECT LEFT(POST_BODY, 40) FROM BLOG_POSTS
```

It's normally best to let the database 'do the work'. However, if you're going to use the rest of the blog post when the user clicks 'more', select the entire post and split it using Ruby's string methods.

Comment: I would prefer this approach over the other one, depending on how many post previews you are showing in a page. If not too many, then the other approach is slightly easier to do. IMO, as a start, I would do the other way, and if performance becomes a problem I would do it using a select statement like above.